# Odd Perl Regex Behavior with Parens

Tags: regex, perl, url, matching

I'm pulling in some Wikipedia markup and I'm wanting to match the URLs in relative (on Wikipedia) links.  I don't want to match any URL containing a colon (not counting the protocol colon), to avoid special pages and the like, so I have the following code:

```
while ($body =~ m|<a href="(?<url>/wiki/[^:"]+)|gis) { 
  my $url = $+{url};
  print "$url\n";
}
```

unfortunately, this code is not working quite as expected.  Any URL that contains a parenthetical [i.e. `/wiki/Eon_(geology`)] is getting truncated prematurely just before the opening paren, so that URL would match as `/wiki/Eon_`.  I've been looking at the code for a bit and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Can anyone provide some insight?

Comment: Your regex doesn't match `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eon_(geology)` at all - it'll only match URLs that *start with* `/wiki/`.

Comment: Can you post a short but complete snippet of code that reproduces the problem, preferably also on http://ideone.com/ ? I'm having hard time seeing it `:)`

Comment: @Tim I corrected the URLs to reflect the actual, relative, URLs which I am looking for.

Comment: @Kobi I'm not sure what more I can provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything wrong in this code as it stands, so long as your Perl is new enough to support these RE features. Tested with Perl 5.10.1.

```
$body = <<"__ENDHTML__";
<a href="/wiki/Eon_(geology)">Body</a> Blah blah 
<a href="/wiki/Some_other_(parenthesis)">Body</a>
__ENDHTML__

while ($body =~ m|<a href="(?<url>/wiki/[^:"]+)|gis) { 
  my $url = $+{url};
  print "$url\n";
}
```

Are you using an old Perl?

Comment: Exactly, the regex and the code works just fine. OP please prove us wrong. ;)

Comment: $] is 5.012003.  Your sample code is working, so now I'm really unsure where problem is.

Comment: OK, I just figured out the problem and it was some something dumb I did.  I was previously "cleaning" the markup and was inadvertently stripping the parenthetical.  Sorry to waste people's time, though this obviously working solution did get me looking at my code more closely.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't anchor the RE to the end of the string.  Put a " afterwards.

While that is a problem, it isn't the problem he was trying to solve.  The problem he was trying to solve was that there was nothing to match the method/hostname (http://en.wiki...) in the RE.  Adding a .*? would help that, before the "(?"

Comment: This doesn't explain why it's not matching the parentheses, though.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: That is because you didn't allow any regex for http://....   Stick a ".*" before the "(?"  Sorry, I mistook who generated the problem.  I see that you figure that out.  I still mentioned a problem with his RE which will prevent it from doing what he wanted.

Comment: Adding a `.*` (with the `s` flag) will most likely match most of the article, at least as far as the last link.

Comment: @Seth the character exclusion class [^:"] should implicitly terminate the URL when it hits a double quote.  Am I wrong?  Also, this question has nothing to do with method/hostname, because, as originally stated, these are relative URLs.

Comment: @theraccoonbear: THe problem is it also implicitly terminates when it hits a :, so it will inappropriately match a URL with a : in it.  According to the spec that is not desired.